# A certain theme is forcing it's singular post layout

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, page-template

I am using Elementor pro to edit a certain custom post type (through an elementor theme builder template) to look a certain way.

But the singular post type of that custom post, isn't changing to represent the chosen template (that is applied & active for that post type).

I have tried switching themes and with any other theme I tried, the template is applied perfectly on that CPT singular posts.

Therefore my conclusion is that the current theme forces its singular post layout on all posts and all post types, and doesn't allow elementor templates to override it.

Anyone encountered something similar and has any custom snippet ideas of how this can be resolved? Switching themes is currently not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Compatibility between Elementor and particular themes is an issue you need to raise with their developers. Support for third party themes and plugins is not provided here.

Comment: It has nothing to do with compatibility. The question is simple: How to stop a theme from forcing their post templates or change their priority?

Comment: That’s not how themes work. If a theme doesn’t work with Elementor, that’s a compatibility issue.